# Can SSIS jobs be async?

Tags: ssis, async-await

I'm a bit confused on whether the `async` methods work properly with an SSIS job or not.  The Script Task items create a visual studio project that targets .NET Framework 4.5, with an output type of Class Library.

If I make the main method `public async void Main()` and inside it do `await` calls against `async` methods, is it really waiting?

Some of the posts I've seen here imply it does, and others imply it does not.

Comment: How would one test this (I know a bit about SSIS but don't have enough background to understand the end goal of a having an async Execute Script Task)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, SSIS Framework and base .Net classes were created well before advance of 4.5 Framework and its async execution model. You have to implement SSIS methods as they are declared; the declaration is classic and not async.
When I need to call some async methdos inside SSIS scripts or custom components, I do in with Task.Run wrapper like this

```
mRes=Task.Run(async () =>
    await AsyncMethod(...).ConfigureAwait(false)).Result;
```

Perhaps this is not the best approach, but it allows to run `AsyncMethod` on a ThreadPool.
You benefit little from `async` calls in SSIS, since SSIS framework is not *async-ready* itself.

Comment: The HttpClient method only has an async version of Post :(

Comment: I am a late comer to async and await mostly due to coming from a database side and then SSIS and then script tasks. But now that I know about it, it is infuriating to not have that tool inside SSIS. Why the hell would the foreach file not be able to be run async!!!! 1 file at a time... really!!!!!!!!